# SQLite UPDATE multiple values from TextFields Python Kivy

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update

I have a database with columns: names, price, quantity, pcs, ml, gram, comment.How can I correctly update one of this row with values from textfields? Value of names must be changed to value editNames.text etc...

```
def editIngredient(self, obj):
    
    con = sql.connect('sweet.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM sweet""")
    names = self.editNames.text
    price = self.editPrice.text
    quantity = self.editQty.text
    pcs = self.editPcs.state
    ml = self.editMl.state
    gram = self.editGram.state
    comment = self.editComment.text
    now = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    cur.execute(""" UPDATE sweet SET (names,price,quantity,pcs,ml,gram,comment,timeadding) WHERE (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""",
        (names, price, quantity, pcs, ml, gram, comment, now))
```

Comment: don't forget to add `con.commit()` to the end if autocommit mode is not ON

Comment: Thank, I will ;)